# SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Anyone has any idea about the Vulnerability "42873 - SSL Medium Strength Cipher Suites Supported (SWEET32)".The server is hosted under the cloud environment and the OS is 'windows server 2012 R2'. Please guide me to fix this issue securely because it's a production environment.

Awaiting your response.